# Why is my program counting letters and digits not running?

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

I wrote this function tat checks for upper, lower and digits in a string but when I'm trying to run the code this pops up and cant seem to understand the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define size 50

void statistics(char str[], int *lower, int *upper, int *digits) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (islower(str[i]) != 0) {
            *lower = *lower + 1;
        } else
        if (isupper(str[i]) != 0) {
            *upper = *upper + 1;
        } else
        if (isalpha(str[i])) {
            *digits = *digits + 1;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char str[size] = { " " };
    int upper = 0, lower = 0, digits = 0;

    printf("Enter a string:\n");
    gets_s(str);

    statistics(&str[size], &lower, &upper, &digits);
    printf("Lower: %d\nUpper: %d\nDigits %d", lower, upper, digits);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: *"it has an error on the str[]"* Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for providing a full [mcve], that's very helpful. However, it's also considered polite here to include **the full error message that you get** in your question text. That way, people can just look at the error message instead of having to run your code on their machines to get it. This means less work for those trying to help you, which increases the chances of actually getting help here!

Comment: You are passing `&str[size]` into your function. That's a pointer to a memory location after the last character in your character array. And then you are trying to look at the next 50 elements, ie you are far beyond the end of your character array ...

Comment: @MaySwisa: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score. You will be able to upvote once you get enough reputation.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the `gets_s()` function is not portable: it is optional and not supported on many systems. You forget to pass the array size, hence causing undefined behavior. The compiler should output a diagnostic that you should not ignore. You should use `fgets()` instead.
- you should not pass `char` values to the `isupper()` and similar functions because they are only defined for values of the type `unsigned char` and the special negative value `EOF`. Use an `unsigned char` variable or cast the `str[i]` argument as `(unsigned char)str[i]`.
- you pass the address of the end of the char array instead of the beginning. Just pass `str` as the argument to `statistics`. The `statistics` function reads characters beyond the end of the array, invoking undefined behavior, and one of these bytes happens to be a negative `char` value less than `-1` triggering the diagnostic in your Visual C++ compiler runtime. The error message is difficult to interpret, the IDE should point you to the calling code.
- you iterate on the whole array, beyond the null terminator. The contents of the array is undefined beyond the null terminator set by `gets_s()` or `fgets()`. Just stop at the null terminator.
- you test `if (isalpha(ch))` where you probably mean to use `if (isdigit(ch))`
- the `isxxx` functions return a non zero value for true and zero for false. It is idiomatic in C to just write `if (isdigit(c))` instead of `if (isdigit(c) != 0)` which seems redundant.
- defining `size` as a macro is error prone. Use upper case and a more explicit name.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LINE_SIZE 50

void statistics(const char *str, int *lower, int *upper, int *digits) {
    while (*str != '\0') {
        unsigned char ch = *str++;
        if (islower(ch)) {
            *lower += 1;
        } else
        if (isupper(ch)) {
            *upper += 1;
        } else
        if (isdigit(ch) {
            *digits += 1;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char str[LINE_SIZE];
    int upper = 0, lower = 0, digits = 0;

    printf("Enter a string:\n");
    if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
        statistics(str, &lower, &upper, &digits);
        printf("Lower: %d\nUpper: %d\nDigits %d", lower, upper, digits);
    }
    return 0;
}
```